# Getting "access" denied on a shadow request of a remote desktop

Tags: windows, shadow, rdp

I am running the following code in a batch file

```
Mstsc /v:VS-Print-Server /shadow:1 /control /noConsentPrompt
```

But keep getting a "Shadow error, access denied" message, I have set the group policy to allow for remote connections without a prompt, and set the max number of connections to 999999, and set the "AllowRemoteRPC" dword in the registry to 1 as well.

I have gone through a slew of other fixes like local security policy fixes for "Allow log on through Terminal Services" (which also gave me errors) and am at my wits end with getting it to work.

Regular RDP connections work just fine, but the main goal is to just shadow and share the screen of the computer so as to not kick anyone out working on it, or have to check across the office to see if it is free to use.

Windows 10 Pro to Windows 10 pro is the configuration, build 1909.